# What is the alternative to global variables in Azure Function Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless, timer-trigger

Lets say I want to have a TimerTrigger function app that executes every 10 seconds and prints an increasing count(1...2...3...),
how can I achieve this WITHOUT using environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using an Azure Storage account for your function. Create a table within that storage account, and increment the counter there. This has the added benefit of persisting across function restarts.

Since you're using a TimerTrigger, it's implicit that there will only ever be one instance of the function running. If this were not the case, you could end up in a race condition with two or more instances interleaving to incorrectly increment your counter.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp). This is an extension for Azure Functions that allow state in your (orchestrator) functions.

In your case, you can have a single HTTP triggered starter function that starts a long running orchestrator function. The HTTP function passes the initial `count` value to the orchestrator function. You can use the [Timer functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers?tabs=csharp) of Durable Functions to have the orchestrator wait for the specified amount of time before continuing/restarting. After the timer expires, the `count` value is incremented and you can restart the orchestrator function with this new `count` value by calling the `ContinueAsNew` method.

[This periodic work example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-eternal-orchestrations?tabs=csharp#periodic-work-example) is almost what you need I think. You still need to add the initial `count` to be read as the input, and increment it before the `ContinueAsNew` method is called.

If you need more details about Durable Functions, I have [quite some videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoSzmz8jSD1fahiSdKdf4073AOdti_rx8) that explain the concepts.